# 'Cannot read property of undefined' when executing a promise twice

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous

Now i am working with promises to face asynchronous problems. 
Things is, that when i execute the promise for the first time, it works perfect.
But when i execute the same function twice, "Cannot read property of undefined" shows up. Reloading the page solves the problem, but its not the idea for the user to refresh every time.

So i want to know why this happen. The previous promise is still running? If that's so, how do i reset it, or refresh it?

Im using Typescript and angular 4.

Here is the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'ensenanza' of undefined
    at SafeSubscriber._next (notas.service.ts:87)
    at SafeSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrSetError (Subscriber.js:248)
    at SafeSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:188)
    at Subscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:126)
    at Subscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:90)
    at Notification.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Notification.js.Notification.observe (Notification.js:32)
    at QueueAction.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operators/observeOn.js.ObserveOnSubscriber.dispatch (observeOn.js:89)
    at QueueAction.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/scheduler/AsyncAction.js.AsyncAction._execute (AsyncAction.js:111)
    at QueueAction.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/scheduler/QueueAction.js.QueueAction.execute (QueueAction.js:33)
    at QueueScheduler.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/scheduler/AsyncScheduler.js.AsyncScheduler.flush (AsyncScheduler.js:36)
```

And the piece of code im working on

```
asignatura(key) { //obtener x cookie el rbd
        var cod= [];
        var total_listado = [];
        var prom = Promise;
        return prom.resolve(this.datoCurso(this.key)).then( dcurso =>{
            console.log(dcurso);

            this.firebase.list('/sistema/asignaturaRBD').subscribe((asignaturaA) => {

                for (let k = 0; k < asignaturaA.length; k++) {
                    const a = asignaturaA[k];
                    console.log(a.ensenanza +'=='+ dcurso[0].ensenanza +'&&'+ a.nivel +'=='+ dcurso[0].nivel+ '&&'+ a.rbd +'=='+ dcurso[0].rbd);


                    if (a.ensenanza == dcurso[0].ensenanza && a.nivel == dcurso[0].nivel && a.rbd == dcurso[0].rbd) {
                        cod.push({
                            asignatura: a.asignatura,
                            ensenanza: a.ensenanza,
                            nivel: a.nivel})
                            console.log("Paso por if");
                            //total_listado.push({ key: a.$key, asignatura: a.asignatura, ensenanza: a.ensenanza, estado: a.estado, nivel: a.nivel, rbd: a.rbd })
                        }
                    }  

                });
                return this.getNombreAsignatura(cod);
            });

        }
```

Code of datoCurso

```
datoCurso(key) { //get todos los datos x key
            let pushcurso = new Array();

            this.firebase.list('/sistema/curso', {
                query: {
                    equalTo: key,
                    orderByKey: key,
                    limitToFirst: 1
                }
            }).subscribe((datos) => {
                for (let v = 0; v < datos.length; v++) {
                    const c = datos[v];
                    pushcurso.push({
                        ensenanza: c.cod_ensenanza,
                        nivel: c.nivel,
                        rbd: c.rbd
                    });
                    console.log(pushcurso[0].ensenanza+'--'+pushcurso[0].nivel+'--'+pushcurso[0].rbd);
                    // pushcurso = [{nivel: c.nivel, ensenanza: c.cod_ensenanza}];
                }
            });
            return pushcurso;
        }
```

Comment: Please add some code.

Comment: There i added code.

Comment: I answered before the code example provided. Could you please provide code for `this.datoCurso(this.key)` as well?

Comment: Yes. There you go.

Comment: By the way, the previous answer was cool to investigate about it.

Comment: if I understand this line doesn't work? console.log(pushcurso[0].ensenanza+'--'+pushcurso[0].nivel+'--'+pushcurso[0].rbd);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i solved it. I removed promises and put setTimeouts.

Like this:

```
asignatura(key) { //obtener x cookie el rbd
        var cod= [];
        var total_listado = [];
        var prom = Promise;
        var dc = this.datoCurso(this.key);
        setTimeout(() => {
        this.firebase.list('/sistema/asignaturaRBD').subscribe((asignaturaA) => {
                for (let k = 0; k < asignaturaA.length; k++) {
                    const a = asignaturaA[k];
                    if (a.ensenanza == dc[0].ensenanza && a.nivel == dc[0].nivel && a.rbd == dc[0].rbd) {
                        cod.push({
                            asignatura: a.asignatura,
                            ensenanza: a.ensenanza,
                            nivel: a.nivel})
                            console.log("Paso por if");
                            //total_listado.push({ key: a.$key, asignatura: a.asignatura, ensenanza: a.ensenanza, estado: a.estado, nivel: a.nivel, rbd: a.rbd })
                        }
                    }  
                });

        }, 3000);
        return this.getNombreAsignatura(cod);

    }


getNombreAsignatura(n){
        var arr = [];
        console.log(n);
        setTimeout(() => {
        this.getAsignatura().subscribe((data)=>{
            for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                const asignatura = data[i];
                for (let j = 0; j < n.length; j++) {
                    const cod= n[j];
                    if(asignatura.cod_asignatura == cod.asignatura && asignatura.tipo_ensenanza == cod.ensenanza && asignatura.curso == cod.nivel){
                        arr.push({
                            codigo: asignatura.cod_asignatura,
                            nombre: asignatura.detalle
                        })
                        console.log(asignatura);    
                    }
                }

            }
        });
    }, 5000);
        console.log(arr);
        return arr;
    }
```

This oddly works, but works.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need promises here. You can write `datoCurso` method so it returns an observable of some object like this:

```ts
datoCurso(key)
{
    let pushcurso = new Array();

    this.firebase.list('/sistema/curso', {
        query: {
            equalTo: key,
            orderByKey: key,
            limitToFirst: 1
        }
    }).map((datos: any[]) => datos.map(c => ({
        ensenanza: c.cod_ensenanza,
        nivel: c.nivel,
        rbd: c.rbd
    })));
}
```

then you can zip two observables like this and execute your logic on the result:

```ts
Observable.zipArray( // or zipAll - depends on rxjs version
    this.datoCurso(this.key),
    this.firebase.list('/sistema/asignaturaRBD')
).subscribe(([dcurso, asignaturaA]: [any[], any[]]) =>
{
    this.getNombreAsignatura(asignaturaA
        .filter(a => a.ensenanza == dcurso[0].ensenanza && a.nivel == dcurso[0].nivel && a.rbd == dcurso[0].rbd)
        .map(a => ({
            asignatura: a.asignatura,
            ensenanza: a.ensenanza,
            nivel: a.nivel
        })));
});
```

PS: Since I have no idea what this all about - so no guarantees